# Understanding HashMap<K,V>

Tags: java, hashmap

Ok, here is the bit I do not understand.
*If you attempt to retrieve an object using the `get()` method and null is returned, it is still possible that `null` may be stored as the object associated with the key you supplied to the `get()` method. You can determine if this is the case by passing your key of the object to `containsKey()` method for map. This returns `true` if key is stored in the map*
So, how is `containsKey()` supposed to tell me if the **value associated with the key supplied is `null`**?
This is [the reference](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=10WYCnEHM9sC&pg=PR5&dq=Ivor+Horton+Beginning+Java+7&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fA3NT6ypLsO_8wO_q-gB&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAA#553=onepage&q=Ivor%20Horton%20Beginning%20Java%207&f=false) if you wanna check. Page 553

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this simple snippet of code:

```
Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
m.put("key1", "value1");
m.put("key2", null);

System.out.println("m.get(\"key1\")=" + m.get("key1"));
System.out.println("m.containsKey(\"key1\")=" + m.containsKey("key1"));

System.out.println("m.get(\"key2\")=" + m.get("key2"));
System.out.println("m.containsKey(\"key2\")=" + m.containsKey("key2"));

System.out.println("m.get(\"key3\")=" + m.get("key3"));
System.out.println("m.containsKey(\"key3\")=" + m.containsKey("key3"));
```

As you can see I put in the map two values, one of which is null. Thene i asked the map for three values: two of them are present (one is null), one is not. Look at the result:

```
m.get("key1")=value1
m.containsKey("key1")=true
m.get("key2")=null
m.containsKey("key2")=true
m.get("key3")=null
m.containsKey("key3")=false
```

The second and the third are the tricky part. `key2` is present with null value so, using `get()` you cannot discriminate whether the element is not in the map or is in the map with a `null` value. But, using `containsKey()` you can, as it returns a `boolean`.

Comment: Alright, that explained it properly. In real life programming, I will have to use `containsKey()` first to check if the key is valid and then display the value associated with it. If not then display a message or throw an exception :)

Comment: @FasihKhatib that is only really necessary if you are storing `null`s in the Map. If you never store `null` in the Map, there isn't much of a point in checking for valid null mappings.

Answer (score 9):

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("Foo", null);
System.out.println(map.containsKey("Foo"));
System.out.println(map.containsKey("Boo"));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
true
false
```

---

`get()` returns `null` in two cases:

- The key does not exist in the map.
- The key does exist but the associated value is `null`.

You can't tell from `get()` which is true. However, `containsKey()` will tell you if the key was present in the map, regardless of whether its associated value was `null`.

Comment: which is pretty much what i said in the post above.

Comment: yeah, what the book says is that it is supposed to help me check if the V value of the HashMap<K,V> is null.

Answer (score 3):

```
(get() == null && containsKey()) == value is null
```

Answer (score 1):

containsKey would tell you if the key is in the hashmap at all. Consider the case where a key is present with null value and the other case in which the key which you are looking for is not at all in the hashmap.