# What is the <K, V> thing in a hashmap, and how do I use it in my own class?

Tags: java, generics, collections, hashmap, instance

I have been trying to simply get a name for what the <> part of the declaration is called, to no luck. Can anyone tell me what it's called, how I can use it in my own class? For instance I may want to try and make my own kind of collection, and use `new MyThing<String>` for instance. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you mean `generics`?  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: @StephenC I didn't know it was called generics.

Comment: Or this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490091/java-generics

Comment: @Stephen This should stay open, because it does use the word "generics" which makes it a different question ("what is this called? How do I do it?")

Comment: @user2507230 - Well now you do!  (But seriously, any good Java textbook written in the last 5 to 8 years will cover this topic.  It is fundamental to Java since Java 5.)

Comment: @Doorknob - what is the likelihood that someone else (who doesn't have the term "generic" in his Java vocabulary) will come across this Q&A?  IMO, the answer is "pretty small".

Comment: @Stephen Pretty high - the first search that comes to mind is "<K,V> in hashmap java" or "how to use <K,V> in hashmap in my own class"

Comment: You mean like this one?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887209/understanding-hashmapk-v.  Which is the first hit when I search for "<K,V> in hashmap java". See ... duplicates, and duplicates.

Comment: @Stephen Read the body. That question has *nothing* to do with generics.

Comment: I beg to differ.  While the OP doesn't use the word "generic", this has everything to do with generics.  He says *"I have been trying to simply get a name for what the `<>` part of the declaration is called, to no luck."*

Comment: @Stephen the question there is "how is containsKey() supposed to tell me if the value associated with the key supplied is null?" the question here is "what is this and how can I use it myself?"

Comment: @Doorknob - I accuse you of "selective reading" :-).  Anyway, we shall see if this Question survives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the *generic type* declaration of the class. For example, to specify that a map is going to use strings as keys and integers as values:

```
Map<String, Integer> mymap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Answer (score 4):

It's called generics, and here's how you can use it:

```
public class MyClass<MyType> {
    private MyType myItem;
    public MyClass(MyType item) {
        myItem = item;
    }
    public MyType getMyItem() {
        return myItem;
    }
}
```

Conventionally the name of the type (`MyType` in this case) is `T` for "type" and `K` and `V` for "key" and "value", but I'm just making it easier to understand.

You could then do:

```
MyClass<String> m = new MyClass<String>("potato");
System.out.println(m.getMyItem()); // prints "potato"
```

Comment: It's more conventional to use a single uppercase letter as the generic parameter (not its real name).

Comment: @Tom I know, I was in the middle of an edit (answering from a mobile phone is *hard* `:P`)